# Failed upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04, linux-image-extra needs to be reinstalled

Tags: upgrade, 15.04

I tried to update Ubuntu to 15.04 and got this error:

```
SystemError: E:The package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Comment: Either try later or do a fresh install. Fixing failed upgrades is sometimes more effort then it is worth.